# Как использовать Cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Я пытался создать куки, через php так:

```
   setcookie('user', serialize($user), time() + 3600);
   $get_cook = unserialize($_COOKIE['user']);
```

но при попытке вызвать куки "user" на другой странице, куда у меня ведёт переадресация, он пишет что куки user нет, точнее он выводит пустоту.

На другой странице:

```
 $get_cook = unserialize($_COOKIE['user']);
 echo $get_cook["login"];
```

Но всё безуспешно, и он также ничего не выводит. Скажите пожалуйста, как правильно создать куки, чтобы его можно было вызывать на любой странице одного домена?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чтобы увидеть изменения куки, надо обновить страницу. Т.е. установили куки -> перекинули пользователя на другую страницу -> можете пользоватся куками.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста поподробнее? Желательно на практике

Comment: Для начала проверьте что возвращает `serialize($user)`. Потом, судя из Вашего кода, на 10 строке Вы установили куки и на 11, 14 сразу выводите их. Оно так не сработает.  `setcookie` работает так, что оно создает куки по имени и в ответе клиенту отправит их. А `$_COOKIE` содержит куки, которые уже в были посланные в запросе на сервер. Вам после setcookie надо страницу обновить (чтобы куки попали в $_COOKIE.

Comment: Я пробовал получать данные с $user напрямую, и данные выводились, но лишь на странице переадресации (авторизации), а на других же страницах у меня ничего не выводилось. Я пробовал выводить $_COOKIE на странице авторизации, и мне писало что куки создана (без перезагрузки страницы), но после перехода на страницу пользователя, он не мог обнаружить куки, даже с перезагрузкой

Comment: Я не уверен, но сейчас всё работает. Я случайно нашёл здесь же ответ что возможно проблема в том, что я забыл добавить path, сейчас я добавил его, и куки сохранилось, также я смог его вызвать в странице пользователя!

Comment: Кстати, да. Я что-то подумал, что там по стандарту стоит `/`